# CSS Flexbox (Header & Content[overflow: scroll]) with unknown header height

Tags: css, flexbox

Struggling to figure out how I can have a Flexbox with a header (unknown height) and the content (which is scrollable) which should take up the rest of the space that the header is not using.

If I set the header height I have no issues, but because my header can have more or less content (or screen sizes causing content to wrap), I can't set it as a fixed height.

Example Image https://i.stack.imgur.com/GMGvX.jpg

Any ideas on how to achieve the above?

Comment: provide any jsfiddle or demo code which you have tried..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
html,body{
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

main{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  margin: auto;
}

header{
  background-color: #333;
  color: #eee;
}

article{  
  background-color: #eee;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <header>Some Text</header>
  <article>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</article>
</main>
```

this should work, if its not what you want please tell me in the comments

Comment: Thanks mate, works a charm.

I think my issue is that I was setting my hearder to flex: 1 also. Where as it wasn't needed. Legend.